# How can I pass array of string a parameter to function in delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a problem with Delphi.

I wrote a function like this:

```
function MyFunction(arr: array of AnsiString): Boolean;
begin
  //code here
end;
```

And now, when I pass an array of `AnsiString` directly into function, like this, everything works perfectly:

```
MyFunction(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

But, when I try to store this array like this:

```
var arr: array of AnsiString;

procedure MyProcedure;
begin
  arr[0] := ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  MyFunction(arr[0]);
end;
```

There is a mismatch error.

I'm a beginner with Delphi, but this is really confusing.

Comment: You might take a look at this article: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html

Comment: Why are you even using AnsiString?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is this important? For array of string there is the same issue.

Comment: It will become important when your program starts receiving non ASCII data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second example is not functionally identical to the fist example.

The first example is fine.  The function takes an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Open_Arrays) as an input parameter, and you are constructing a fixed array of strings directly in that parameter, which is perfectly fine.  Any array type can be passed to an open array parameter.

In the second example, you are declaring a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) of strings, but you are not allocating any memory for the array, and you are trying to assign its first element (which is a single string) to point at a fixed array of strings.  And then you are trying to pass that element (again, a single string) where an array is expected.  That is why the code fails to compile.

The correct way to write your procedure would like more like this:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
var
  arr: array of AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 3);
  arr[0] := 'one';
  arr[1] := 'two';
  arr[2] := 'three';
  MyFunction(arr);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
var
  arr: array of AnsiString;
begin
  arr := ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  MyFunction(arr);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TAnsiStringArray = array of AnsiString;

procedure MyProcedure;
var
  arr: TAnsiStringArray;
begin
  arr := TAnsiStringArray.Create('one', 'two', 'three');
  MyFunction(arr);
end;
```